# undefined variables can't show error in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I have a very rare error. I use restify in nodejs for a rest service. But sometimes, if some variables or parts of array are undefined, don't stop the server, and I can't catch the error :S. I use "use strict" mode, and I try this to catch uncaught errors, but nothing happens and I can't show errors. Some idea?

```
process.on("uncaughtException", function(err){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to validate the variables individually by checking `typeof variable_name === 'undefined'` and returning an error.

Comment: I found errors using try/catch method that any other method detect. For example undefined requires.

Comment: @user1710825 Can you give a specific code example where the undefined variable isn't raising an exception?